# ItemsControl and DataTemplate binding to itself

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I have Window with ViewModel which has `ObservableCollection<SomeObject>` named `Collection`. `SomeObject` contains two fields named: `Property1` and `Property2`. To that window, I want to add UserControls. UserControl has two dependency properties also named: `Property1` and `Property2`. In the window `xaml` file I created `ItemsControl` like this:

```xml
<ItemsControl
    ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}">

    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel>

            </StackPanel>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

        <DataTemplate>
            <local:SomeUserControl
                Property1="{Binding Path=Property1}"
                Property2="{Binding Path=Property2}"/>
        </DataTemplate>

    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

</ItemsControl>
```

Is this possible to have just one dependency property `SomeObject` in UserControl and bind it in `DataTemlete`? Something like this:

```xml
<DataTemplate>
    <local:SomeUserControl
        SomeObject="{Binding Path=this}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

`this` means object from `Collection` (defined in `ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}`). So basically it's just binding to itself.

---

Edit: the idea I have just got now:

In the `SomeObject` class define getter:

```
public SomeObject GetItself => this
```

and then in `DataTemplate` I can use: `SomeObject="{Binding Path=GetItself}"`. It is working but I think that there has to be a better way to reach this without creating `GetIteself` field.

Comment: The DataContext of the controls in the ItemTemplate is automatically set to the appropriate element of the ItemsSource collection - that is why `Property1="{Binding Path=Property1}"` works in the first place. So if you put only `<local:SomeUserControl/>` into the DataTemplate, the UserControl could still access the `SomeObject` instance via its DataContext property, e.g. by `SomeObject so = (SomeObject)DataContext;`. Note however that doing this creates a dependency on the SomeObject class in the SomeUserControl class, which you don't have when you just bind the control's properties.

Comment: Note also that "itself" is a misleading name, because it's not the control itself, but only the data item on which it operates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it works

```
<DataTemplate>
    <local:SomeUserControl
        SomeObject="{Binding .}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

or just

```
<DataTemplate>
    <local:SomeUserControl
        SomeObject="{Binding}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```